# How much power can the powercell of a lightsaber deliver to the blade?

Tags: star-wars, technology, lightsaber

Lightsabers are extraordinary weapons, they can cut almost anything and reflect blaster bolts, but one of their most amazing feats is the quantity of energy they deliver. I particularly remember this scene where Qui-Gon Jin melts his way through a blast-door :

[image: Qui-Gon melting his way through a door]

How much power, in watts, does the lightsaber's blade need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a quick search, I was pleased to learn that [Someone already did the job for us](http://scienceblogs.com/dotphysics/2010/02/02/power-source-for-a-lightsaber/)!

Check the link for the complete calculations. It uses the color of the melting door to estimate the temperature of the door and approximate many values, like the material of the door and melting point. The estimates seem pretty good, with the lack of anything better.

> ### Temperature
>
> What is the temperature of the metal (I assume it is metal, but it doesn’t really matter) door? Here is a shot of the door being cut (melted) by Qui Gon. I used the PhET simulator to match the color of the heated parts of the door to blackbody temperatures.
>
> [image: i-207a7ca194c3339d3fd63013ef9dee65-2010-02-02_untitled.jpg]
>
> This seems pretty rough, but it is a start. One problem is that the screen captures might be a slightly different color. Oh well, it is close enough.

The final answer around **28 kilowatts**.

Comment: So... not enough to power the Delorian?

Comment: And not enough to cut through Darth Vaders very thin shoulder armour with an intention filled two handed swing.  And yet moments later enough to casually lop through 3 big metal pipes full of gubbins with an overswing.  (Luke vs Vader in ESB.)  Don't analyse it too much!  :-)

Comment: @Jersey 1.21 gigawatts/28 kilowatts is 43210, so you'd need that number of lightsabers to power the DeLorean. Given that there were about 10.000 Jedi alive prior to Order 66, it is unlikely that the entire order had access to that many lightsabers.

Comment: @Grimm IIRC Darth Vader had lightsaber resistant armor.